# how to link manufacturer/brand with product in opencart.?

Tags: opencart

I have added list of manufacturer/brand in opencart. But when i click on any brand /manufacturer it show an error like object not found(like this link http://localhost:8081/nutrition/Whey%20Proteins).
I will attach error screenshot.
**before** 
[image]

**After click on Casein Proteins brands it shows error like this**
[image]

Comment: we can't access your local host :D

Comment: I can notice that the name **"Casein Proteins"** has a space in it, when using OC SEO links you can't use spaces in the name of manufacturers, categories,sub-categories,products ... use a dash **"-"** instead

Comment: @AbdoAdel: I have removed space but but not work still.

Comment: Any one plz help me..

Comment: wait a minute, the link should be something like **"localhost:8081/<OC_ROOT>/nutrition/bla-bla-bla"** , where is the name of the OC folder **<OC_ROOT>**? you can't jump directly from **localhost** to **nutrition**, maybe it's a problem in configuration, can you post your configuration files here?

Comment: my <oc_root> is nutrition itself.>

Comment: oh, I thought that it's a category :D , sorry